# The form box is not aligning to the left side

Tags: html, css

So, I'm getting stuck on this challenge because of this issue with my CSS. The form box which has the input box for email is not aligning on the left in the `.left div`, everything is good in the mobile design but when I try to media queries for the desktop design the input is `width:100%` so I set the `max-width` to 400px so that it looks right to design I'm going for and of course, the input stays in the center, not in the left side.

[Here is the image which is the output that i wanna achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUrlY.jpg)

[Here is the code snippet](https://codepen.io/oceanotrash/pen/BaOmPPo)

Comment: please include [mcve] in the OP not a link to the code

Comment: Remove the margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

You put a dot before the form selector inside the media query, so its looking for a class .form.

```css
.container .form //remove the dot before form here
  {
    margin-left: 0;
    
  }
```